# Stream file to iphone with flask

Tags: python, ios, flask

I am currently doing a file conversion on the fly.

As the file is being converted I am streaming the response to the user as a attachment.  This works fine in Windows, ubuntu, and Android.

For some reason when I try this on iphone it does not work

```
@app.route('/mp3', methods=['POST'])
def generate_large_mp3():
    #convert on fly
    return Response(stream_with_context(mp3), mimetype="audio/mpeg3",
                   headers={"Content-Disposition":
                                "attachment;filename=test.mp3"})
```

I was reading on [this blogpost](http://blog.asgaard.co.uk/2012/08/03/http-206-partial-content-for-flask-python) about a issue in IOS when they are doing a send_file that IOS wants the size of the file.

Is there any way i can do this with stream instead of sendfile, as it is working already for everything but IOS.

If i `"Content-Range": int` to the response, the server shows the download as streaming till done.  But the Iphone simply shows a play button.

Comment: You haven't described the nature of 'it doesn't work' or what client is doing the request.

Comment: @pvg the file when clicked to download simply loads a play screen, and the file doesn't download.  The stream response never goes beyond the first iteration

Comment: you mean in mobile safari?

Comment: yeah, whats bizzar is there is no error code on the server that I can find.

Comment: Hello, have you resolved this? I have the same issue, iPhone safari does not  playback .mov files when served by flask. Total silence, no errors. Am I missing the right mime-type